# Unification of forces in black hole singularity?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, hawking-radiation, grand-unification, black-hole-firewall

If at the center of a black hole a singularity or singularity-like state is reached, wouldn't you have the fundamental forces reaching unification energy? In which case, it would seem that a black hole wouldn't have an electric charge since electromagnetism wouldn't be a separate force from gravity in the black hole. Yet I've heard the black holes are supposed to have a charge, and that information is supposed to be conserved when it enters the black hole. But if the forces unify, you would lose that information, and you'd have no charge.

**Edit:**

To make my question more precise: In the [No-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem), it was thought that black holes have only three externally measurable properties: mass, angular momentum, and electrical charge. How is it that a black hole would have an electrical charge, however, if at the center of the black hole you would reach unification energies and electrical charge should cease to mean anything?

Also, there's the [black hole information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox) where the idea is that the quantum information of the infalling matter must be somehow preserved. Yet, again, at unification it would seem that the information would be converted into one original unified force, as was the case just after the big bang, and information about charge, or any of the quantum numbers associated with the strong or weak force would be erased.

So, my question is, taking into account current ideas on quantum gravity from Hawking and others, doesn't unification of the four forces at the center of the black hole affect these issues? And if not, why not?

Comment: @safesphere Specifically, I'm referring to the no-hair theorem which states that a black hole would have a measurable electric charge. And the black hole information paradox which deals precisely with what happens inside a black hole, since it eventually does all come back out via hawking radiation, as the black hole evaporates.

Comment: @safesphere Oh, ok, I understand. In my question though I'm talking about current theoretical ideas about quantum gravity, the kind of thinking that led to the holographic principle, Hawking radiation, etc. I understand it's all currently theoretical.